# How to build mym (matlab to mysql) on 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mysql, matlab

Has anyone been able to get mym (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mym/) to build on a 64-bit Win7 machine? And if so would you mind posting or linking your steps to do so?

My particulars:
Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit OS
MATLAB Version 7.13.0.564 (R2011b)
Microsoft VS 2010 Ver. 10.0.30319.1
MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.21, for Win64 (x86)

I ran "mex -setup" and I was able to compile and run "yprime.c"

I downloaded and installed zlib (http://www.zlib.net/), which is what the readme file for mym says to do.

Here is the mex command that I am using:

```
mex -IC:\zlib-1.2.6 -I'C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\include' ...
      -L'C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt' ...
      -L'C:\zlib-1.2.6' -lzlib -lmysqlclient mym.cpp
```

I get a bunch of "already defined in MSVCRT.lib" error messages. e.g.:

```
LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: _encoded_null already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) 
LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _set_invalid_parameter_handler already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll) 
LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _initterm_e already defined in MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR100.dll)
```

I admit that I'm stumped at this point and there is not a whole lot of helpful info out there on the world wide web.

UPDATE:

From my notes, here are the steps that I took to get this to work (Note: I'm no longer working on the project that needed this so I hope things haven't changed since I did this)

1. Install 32-bit MATLAB if not already available.  (I believe mym requires 32-bitbit 
   MATLAB though I am not 100% sure about this.)
2. Download zlib source code (http://www.zlib.net/).  The version that I downloaded was 1.2.6; the source was contained in a zip archive called zlib126.zip
3. Unzip the zlib source code and place in desired location—I placed contents in folder “C:\zlib 1.2.6”
4. Download zlib124_masm_obj.zip (http://www.findthatfile.com/search-37735452-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-zlib124_masm_obj.zip.htm).  (NOTE:  After building zlib while writing these notes, I noticed that there is a zlib125_masm_obj.zip available.)
5. Copy the contents of the directory “contrib\masmx86” in the zip archive to the directory “...\zlib 1.2.6\contrib\masmx86” directory (NOTE:  This step was necessary because when I tried to build zlib I got an error message regarding missing files.  I don’t remember how or where I found the solution to this.  I forgot to note the web site.  I found the link listed in step 4 while writing these notes.)
6. Build zlib with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:
   a.  Double-click file the MVS solution file, zlibvc.sln, in folder “...\zlib 1.2.6\contrib\vstudio\vc10\” to start MVS2010.  (NOTE:  When I did this I got six projects listed under solution zlibvc.)
   b.  Build the project.  (NOTE:  When I did this, only project zlibvc built successfully but that was the only one I needed.  Also, I set the project properties so that the Configuration was a Release build instead of a Debug build.)
   c.  Verify that zlibwapi.lib is generated in the folder “...\zlib 1.2.6\contrib\vstudio\vc10\x86\ZlibDllRelease”.
7. Download mym (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mym/).  The version that I installed was 1.36.  The source was contained in a zip archive called mym_src_v1.36.zip.
8. Unzip the mym archive and place the contents in desired location—I placed contents in folder C:\Users\dossow1\Documents\MATLAB\mym_src_v1.36
9. Copy the file msvc100opts.bat from the directory “C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011b\bin\win32\mexopts” to the directory where mym was stored.
10. Edit the msvc100opts.bat file to add option “/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD” to the “set LINKFLAGS” line.
11. Start MATLAB, cd to the directory where mym was stored, and compile mym with the following command:

mex -f .\msvc100opts.bat -I'C:\zlib-1.2.6' 
    -I'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include' ...
    -L'C:\zlib-1.2.6\contrib\vstudio\vc10\x86\ZlibDllRelease' ...
   -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt' ...
    -llibmysql  -lzlibwapi .\mym.cpp

12. Do one of the following:
    a.  Copy the following DLL’s to the directory where mym is stored:
    i.  zlibwapi.dll from “...\zlib-1.2.6\contrib\vstudio\vc10\x86\ZlibDllRelease”
    ii. libmysql.dll from “...\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt”
    b.  Add the directories where zlibwapi.dll and libmysql.dll are located to the system path (via Control Panel| Advanced System Properties | Environment Variables | System Variables | Path)

Now mym should be ready to run!!

Comment: You will need to make sure every library ( including zlib ) is built to support 64-bit otherwise built everything as a x86 assembly and install the 32 version of MatLab, MySQL, ect.

Comment: I'm getting closer ... After some research with Mr. Google I added /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMTD to the "set LINKFLAGS" line in the mexopts file Matlab is using (in my case MSVC100OPTS.BAT).  That got rid of the "already defined" errors.  Now I'm left with a handful of "unresolved external symbol" errors in mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj).  BTW, Thanks for the response Ramhound.

Comment: Could you indicate whether the question is still open? Or if you have found the answer please post it for future reference.

Comment: I did eventually get this to work, I'll list the steps above because they are too long to fit here.